# Syntax for a RedirectToAction() with an id for a div?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got:

```
 return RedirectToAction("ManageCampaigns", new { campaignID = Model.LeadSalesCampaignID });
```

Which works fine.  It sends the user to `ManageCampaigns?campaignID=1`.  But now, I want to send the user to:

```
ManageCampaigns?campaignID=1#divID
```

What would the syntax be to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `RedirectToAction` return a `RedirectResult` using the `Url.Action()` method and format the string with the div id.

Such as

```
return Redirect($"{Url.Action("ManageCampaigns", new { campaignID = Model.LeadSalesCampaignID })}#divId");
```

`Url.Action` will capture your action url as a string and then you simply append the div id to the end of it.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  I will mark it as the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me.